# How to execute docker health check only one time?

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I use flask server in docker container.
I want to automatically send request to flask server when flask server is starting.
I used health check in dockerfile, but, I want to send request only one time, not iteratively.
How to execute docker health check only one time?
This is my health check code.
`HEALTHCHECK --interval=3m --timeout=300s CMD python api/initRequest.py || exit 0`

and initRequest.py

```
import base64
import requests
import json


def warmUp():
    with open('./api/static/sample1.png', 'rb') as f1:
        f1_B = base64.b64encode(f1.read())
    f1_B = f1_B.decode('utf-8')
    with open('./api/static/sample2.png', 'rb') as f2:
        f2_B = base64.b64encode(f2.read())
    f2_B = f2_B.decode('utf-8')
    model_names = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID"]
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    for model in model_names:
        data = {
            "model_name": model,
            "img":[
                {
                    "img1": "data:image/png;base64,"+f1_B,
                    "img2": "data:image/png;base64,"+f2_B,
                }
            ]
        }
        payload = json.dumps(data)
        response = requests.request("POST", "http://localhost/verify", headers=headers, data=payload)

    data = { 
        "img": [
            "data:image/png;base64,"+f1_B
        ]
    }
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.request("POST", "http://localhost/analyze", headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response


warmUp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can run health check only once, but you can try below option that will `initRequest.py` execute once and then it will ignore further execution base on condition.

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD sh -c "if [ ! -f /tmp/health.txt ]; then touch /tmp/health.txt && python api/initRequest.py || exit 0 ; else echo \"initRequest.py already executed\"; fi"
```